# Custom object list view filter criteria does not return results

Tags: custom-object, lookup, list-view, filters

This is a pretty basic question but I have a list view that I created on a custom object that should be returning results but is not. Object B has a lookup field to Object A,.

So lets say I have 2 Object A records and the names are:
"Some Text" and "Some Text 2014-2015"

I have a list view created on Object B and the filter criteria is:

```
ObjectB.ObjectA EQUALS Some text
```

Which returns 1 record. If I change the filter criteria to

```
ObjectB.ObjectA STARTS WITH Some text
```

It returns both records. Works good like this, but I need to only return the record for this year. So I changed the criteria to:

```
ObjectB.ObjectA EQUALS Some text  2014-2015
```

Which should return 1 record ("Some Text 2014-2015") but instead returns none. Even if I change teh criteria to

```
ObjectB.ObjectA STARTS WITH Some text 2014
```

It returns no results. It seems that once I put the year in the criteria the view stops returning results. This is being done in the UI and not in code. Has anyone encountered this before? I'm sure I must be missing something simple.

Thanks!

Comment: How about using "ObjectB.ObjectA CONTAINS Some text 2014".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you probably want records for this year, not last year, you'll need both 2014 and 2015 in your search string, likewise you would need 2015 and 2016 for next year. Try this:

[image: Search Criteria]

If you need even more complex requirements, then this interface can almost certainly handle them, eg you could do a query like this:
[image: More Complex Search Criteria]

Comment: I unfortunately cannot use that criteria as I have different record names based on the year eg: Lead salesperson 2014-2015,  Junior Salesperson 2014-2015 etc...

Comment: Ok. Depending on wether you want to filter one of these records out or keep them in, you can write different filters. Currently, the filter I've got above will get both of them. I'll add a couple more points to the answer.

Comment: Let me know your exact requirements - I'm certain they can be achieved using this interface.

Comment: I had to include some extra exclusions but your method worked as a work around.  The funny thing is that other string combinations worked just fine and this problem also doesnt appear in my sandbox. I still don't know why i cant use the equals operator for this particular case but as long as it works I'm happy. Thanks!

Comment: Great - interesting to hear about the possible length restrictions to the filter params - you might have found a hidden SF limit.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
ObjectB.ObjectA CONTAINS Some text 2014-2015
```

OR

```
ObjectB.ObjectA CONTAINS Some text 2014
```

Comment: I second "ObjectB.ObjectA CONTAINS Some text 2014", since dashes can make things tricky.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried both those scenarios and neither work. The only filter criteria that works is if I use "starts with" and I do not include 2014-2015 (or even just 2014)

Comment: The funny thing is this filter criteria normally works in creating accurate list views. The only difference I can tell is that this criteria is longer than others. I wonder if there is a limit on how many characters the filter criteria can be?

For example:
ObjectB.ObjectA EQUALS Salesperson 2014-2015 works

ObjectB.ObjectA EQUALS Some text 2014-2015 does not. THis oen is actually 35 characters and I wonder if its hitting a limit?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there are no extra spaces in the criteria value. For instance, your 3rd attempt shows 2 spaces instead on 1. I tested in my dev instance and the following does provide the results you are looking for:

[image: List View Criteria]

Comment: Yes that extra space was a typo while I was posting this question. I copy and paste the record name directly into the filter criteria so I don't have any extra spaces, but no dice.